# zf2, application.config -> config_glob_paths, in yaml format

Tags: zend-framework2

I've setup my hole application using YAML formatted config files. When it comes to the global paths of module_listener_options in the application.config file it ends all the fun with the following stack trace:

### Application config

```yaml
modules:
- # ... a few different modules

module_listener_options:
  config_glob_paths:
  - config/global/{,*.}{shared,private}.yaml

  module_paths:
  - # ... the module paths
```

### Stacktrace

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Config\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'You didn't specify a Yaml callback decoder' in /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Config/Reader/Yaml.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Config/Factory.php(81): Zend\Config\Reader\Yaml-&gt;fromFile('config/global/d...')
#1 /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(356): Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile('config/global/d...')
#2 /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(152): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener-&gt;addConfigByPath('config/global/{...', 'glob_path')
#3 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener-&gt;onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(464): call_u in /home/erik/Projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Config/Reader/Yaml.php on line 100
```

I guess I need to inject a YAML decoder to the YAML reader. I use [Symfonys YAML component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/yaml.html) for this task in other parts of the code.

**So the question I have for you** is how do I inject this decoder to the factory? Or, if there is an other way of doing this, then how else could this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that I could solve this by adding the following `init` function to a Module class:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser as YamlParser,
    Zend\Config\Factory as ConfigFactory;

// ...

public function init()
{
  // This first line is just for the shorter yml suffix
  ConfigFactory::registerReader( 'yml', 'yaml' );

  // Adding the parser to the reader
  $decoder = new YamlParser();
  $reader  = ConfigFactory::getReaderPluginManager()->get( 'yaml' );
  $reader->setYamlDecoder( [ $decoder, 'parse' ] );
}
```

---

I'm still very interested in an alternative way of solving this though.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they use an external lib for the parser

If you want to use an external YAML reader you have to pass the callback function in the constructor of the class. For instance, if you want to use the Spyc library

```
// include the Spyc library
require_once ('path/to/spyc.php');

$reader = new Zend\Config\Reader\Yaml(array('Spyc','YAMLLoadString'));
$data   = $reader->fromFile('/path/to/config.yaml');
```

You can also instantiate the Zend\Config\Reader\Yaml without any parameter and specify the YAML reader in a second moment using the setYamlDecoder() method.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.config.reader.html

This solution solved the problem for me, because i don't use any other yaml parser for the moment